# Nginx-rtmp не транскодит поток в HLS

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, hls

Поток не транскодится совсем (отсутствуют .m3u8 файлы), однако на rtmp принимает нормально.
[Конфиг](http://pastebin.com/3rENDnNu).

---

Детально:

- Файлы (m3u8) в целевой папке **не создаются** (отсутствие проверяется непосредственно в папке и по логу ошибок (2: No such file or directory))
- hls доступен из коробки
- кодеки используются совместимые (для звука - aac)

Ещё заметил странность (или не странность) что на rtmp endpointе также значится локалхост как принимающий поток (зритель)
p.s. бонусом хотелось бы спросить как именно вывести количество смотрящих человек (зрителей) и статус стрима (онлайн/оффлайн)

---

UPD: Исправимы ли локалхосты в статистике? (можно ли каким-либо чудесным образом выводить IP-адреса зрителей?)

[image: localhosts]

Comment: Товарищи, ау, вы где?